# How to prevent escaping on Zend Form Select : Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, escaping, zend-form

how to prevent escaping html on zend form elemnt ? My code is not work at all

```
$this->addElement('Select', 'forum_icon', array(
        'label' => 'Forum Icon',
        'value' => $this->_forum->FORUM_ICON,
        'escape' => false,
        'multiOptions' => $icons
    ));
```

i try another method but it still not work

```
$this->forum_icon->setAttrib('escape', false);
```

thanks in advance,

Brian

Comment: You cannot do it the 'easy way'. You need to amke your own FormSelect view helper without escaping.

Comment: yeah that make me got a headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your decorator for Select element that generates HTML for select with unescaped value. For example:

```
class My_Select_Decorator extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        // Generate HTML markup
        return $markup;
    }
}
```

Refer to these articles for more information:

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/212-The-simplest-Zend_Form-decorator.html

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/08/07/zend_form-decorator-tips/

Comment: the select element can't render image inside tag option, this because dtd format.